# Regex to extract specific domain names in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have thousands of URLs and I want to extract domain names. I am using the following regex to do this: `http://|https://|www\\.`

This manages to extract domains like so:

```
elpais.com
veren.elpais.com
canaris7.es
vertele.eldiario.es
eldiario.es
```

The problem is that I want to only extract the domain -- that is, both vertele.eldiario.es and eldiario.es should give me eldiario.es.

I have used `urltools` as well, but it doesn't seem to be doing the job. I need to extract the domain because I need to have a proper count of the specific domains in all URLs. I am interested in a regex that can extract TLDs ending in both .com and .es.

Comment: You could reverse the string, take everything after the first dot, and reverse it back

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem when the domain name has a prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression `.*\\.(.*\\.(com|es))` used with `sub` to call the group (which is between parentheses) will do it.

```
url <-  c(
  "http://www.elpais.com",
  "http://www.veren.elpais.com",
  "http://www.canaris7.es",
  "http://www.vertele.eldiario.es",
  "http://www.eldiario.es"
)

sub(".*\\.(.*\\.(com|es))", "\\1", url)

[1] "elpais.com"  "elpais.com"  "canaris7.es" "eldiario.es" "eldiario.es"
```

**Edit following the comment from @Corion to another answer:**

If you are concerned about url having more complex suffixes, then you can use:

`.*\\.(.*\\.(com|es)).*`

```
url <-  c(
  "http://www.elpais.com",
  "http://www.veren.elpais.com",
  "http://www.canaris7.es",
  "http://www.vertele.eldiario.es",
  "http://www.eldiario.es",
  "http://www.google.es.hk",
  "http://www.google.com.br"
)

sub(".*\\.(.*\\.(com|es)).*", "\\1", url)

[1] "elpais.com"  "elpais.com"  "canaris7.es" "eldiario.es" "eldiario.es"
[6] "google.es"   "google.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you just want the last two components of the URL.  You can get that from `sub` and a regular expression.

```
URLs = c("http://www.elpais.com",
"http://veren.elpais.com",
"http://www.canaris7.es",
"http://vertele.eldiario.es",
"http://eldiario.es")

sub(".*\\b(\\w+\\.\\w+)", "\\1", URLs)
[1] "elpais.com"  "elpais.com"  "canaris7.es" "eldiario.es" "eldiario.es"
```

Comment: This will fail for domains like `google.co.hk` or `google.com.br` - see https://publicsuffix.org/ for a list of the suffixes that need to be considered.

Comment: But the OP is asking for url "ending in both .com and .es"

Comment: @Corion, I addressed that in my updated answer, but keeping `.com` and `.es` to match the OP's question